# Redirect from one MVC to another MVC application with querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Using .net core 2.0 MVC, C#

I have an application in MVC that has a menu on the UI. One of the menu item contains the redirect to another application. So when user clicks on that item I make an redirect to another application within the same IIS.

So I wanted to know:
- What is the best approach to make an redirect to another application withing the same IIS. Basically to another controller and action in the target application.
- How can I pass some querystring params along the redirect. I want to pass a string value.
- On the target application whats the best place to grab the query string values?

Would appreciate inputs.
Thanks

Comment: Clicking a link and going to another *host* is not called a redirect.  Your question isn't very clear.  If it really is a href on an anchor or some *client side action* you can do anything you want.

Comment: I have 2 applications under the same domain as Application1: https://www.test.com/Site1 and Application1: https://www.test.com/Site2. As mentioned on Site1 there is a menu item that redirects to Site2. Is Response.Redirect a way to redirect here. How can I pass some string value from site1 to site2 . Cookies?

Comment: If you're using MVC, you should almost **never** use reponse.redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hosted on the same server or not, applications are separate entities. In other words, if you need to link to another website (whether it be one you control or not), you'll need to include the full absolute URL:

```
<a href="http://myothersite.com?key=value">Click me!</a>
```

There's no way to generate this as you could for a URL internal to your web app. You also simply construct the query string you want manually, since again, there's no way to generate this for a separate web app.

On the other side, this is just basic modelbinding. Generally speaking, any query string value can be bound directly to an action param of the same name. For example, with the address above, you'd just need an action like:

```
public IActionResult Index(string key)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris this worked. One ques though, I can see the querystring param in my address bar. Any way to hide them. I believe then using cookies instead of querystring is the way for this?

Comment: No. If you intend to develop for the web, you should familiarize yourself with the HTTP protocol. Data is either passed in the URL as a query string or in the request body. While the spec doesn't specifically prohibit GET requests from having a request body, there's no client I know of that natively supports that. In other words, for GET, all you've got is the query string. If you do a POST, you can send the data as part of the request body, so it's at least not visible in the address bar, but there's no true way to hide the data. Anyone can inspect the request body if they want.

Comment: To keep to the same protocol you can remove it, IE `href="//myothersize.com?key=value"`.

Comment: `There's no way to generate this as you could for a URL internal to your web app` - Well, you could, but you would need to build the functionality yourself. Perhaps that should read `no built-in way`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside App1 View (cshtml):

```
<a href="domain2.com/home/test?name=john">Link</a>
```

Inside app2 home controller

```
public ActionResult Test(string name)
{
   //do whatever you want with name.
   return View();
}
```